# 1004 Error in small sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have this extremely small sub in my project that is giving me error 1004 on its last line. I have no idea why this is happening as this line is used elsewhere in the project with no trouble at all.

```
Sheets(p1 & " Raw Results").Copy After:=Sheets(p1 & " Raw Results")
    ActiveSheet.name = p1 & " Raw Results Temp."
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=24, Header:=xlYes
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, sometimes I can reproduce this error, sometimes I can't. I can't figure out the pattern. Can you show what's on the sheet?

Comment: Can't show, but I'll describe, the sheet is a large-ish database, across the top are the headers for each column of data, in column 24 there are a collection of strings, there are duplicates that I need to remove. Does that help?

Comment: Not really. If there is no data in column 24, I can trigger the error, but only *once*: if I then add data there it works, then if I remove the data from column 24 it does *not* give the error again. Smells like an Excel-VBA bug.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error. Can you upload your workbook so that we can test it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I am unable to trigger the error even when there is no data in that column

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that Siddharth, I would love to! This is really 'bug'ging me *ha*. I have tried just using the last line elsewhere in the project (on the sheet p1 & " Raw Results") and it worked instance. Very confusing.

Comment: Yep agree with @SiddharthRout. I use XL2010 , doesn't error out.

Comment: OK, I have worked around this issue now. Applied the removeduplicates earlier in the project, think there might be an issue if jeanfrancois experienced similar issues.

Comment: Btw, when you mean last line it is the line with the remove duplicate?

Comment: You may check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818808/en), but error 1004 also happens if I run your code twice: the program tries to rename a new sheet with the same name as the one previously created, and it fails (but I guess you have already checked this).

Comment: Does it always happen with any specific sheet? If yes, then try recreating a sheet?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, in an attempt to reply to you, despite having a workaround, I did go back and try with a different sheet, and it turns out it was the sheet that caused the issues, I think it may have something to do with the type of table it was creating. I hope that answers your questions, I won't be able to help anymore, as I'm leaving the office.